# python import error cx_Oracle in macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos-sierra, cx-oracle

I have macOS Sierra 10.12.3, and I need to connect to an Oracle database through python. I installed cx_Oracle following [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/thom-nic/6011715), using pip. I get the following error message when importing cx_Oracle in ipython (Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)):

```
In [1]: import cx_Oracle
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d1ecebcba3d2> in <module>()
----> 1 import cx_Oracle

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/dufoudav/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libclntsh.dylib.12.1
    Referenced from: /Users/dufoudav/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-darwin.so
        Reason: image not found
```

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Try the following below, things are a little different for installing oracle instant_client on Mac OS Sierra vs the older versions of MAC OSX

Answer (score 0):

## Installing cx_Oracle for Python/ Mac OS Sierra

Download the following files from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html)

instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip
instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip

- [instantclient-basic-$VERSION-macosx-x64.zip](http://download.oracle.com/otn/mac/instantclient/121020/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip)
- [instantclient-sdk-$VERSION-macosx-x64.zip](http://download.oracle.com/otn/mac/instantclient/121020/instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-12.1.0.2.0.zip)

Create a directory `/usr/local/lib/share/oracle`

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/lib/share/oracle
export VERSION=12.1.0.2.0
export ARCH=x86_64
    
mkdir -p $ORACLE_HOME
```

Copy Instant Client Basic & SDK to `/usr/local/lib/share/oracle`

```
cp instantclient-basic-macos.x64-$VERSION.zip $ORACLE_HOME
cp instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-$VERSION.zip $ORACLE_HOME
```

Unpack both files to that directory:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME
tar -xzf instantclient-basic-macos.x64-$VERSION.zip
tar -xzf instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-$VERSION.zip
```

Create Symbolic links in the instant client folder in `/user/local/lib/share/oracle`

```
cd instantclient_12_1
ln -s libclntsh.dylib.12.1 libclntsh.dylib
ln -s libocci.dylib.12.1 libocci.dylib

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
```

now you can get rid of the zip files you downloaded as they aren't needed anymore

```
cd /usr/local/lib/share/oracle
rm instantclient-basic-macos.x64-$VERSION.zip
rm instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-$VERSION.zip
```

move all the files & folders outside of /instantclient_12_1 to the parent directory `/usr/local/lib/share/oracle`

```
mv  -v $ORACLE_HOME/instantclient_12_1/* /$ORACLE_HOME/
rm -rf instantclient_12_1/
```

You should be able to install cx_Oracle now.

### Troubleshooting

If you're experiencing `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-21561: OID generation failed` Get the hostname of your computer by typing in terminal

```
hostname
```

copy this value and add it to your `/etc/hosts` file with your favorite text editor(i'm using vi in this case)

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

on the line that has `127.0.0.1       localhost` at the end of it put a space and enter your hostname given to you earlier. below, you see MYMACSNAME, replace that portion with your hostname you received

```
127.0.0.1       localhost MYMACSNAME
```